# React Native Keyboard Dismiss has a Delay with grey area

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

In the React Native app I have implemented dismiss keyboard. However when the keyboard is dismissed from scroll view, there is a delay and a grey area will show up before the keyboard disappears. How can I avoid that from happening?

[image: Dismiss Keyboard Delay]

Comment: It'll be helpful if you provide some code, so that we can figure out the problem.

Comment: it seems you might have performance issues please share your code for more clarifications to the others.

Answer (score 1):

The grey area looks like the tableViewCell being selected.
To change the  selectionStyle in swift it would be: `cell.selectionStyle = .blue` or `.none`
The delay is a little more difficult. I would make sure I am running on a device to test it and make sure the function that dismisses the keyboard is being called from the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar issue, ended up setting `height` on my wrapping view when the `keyboardWillHide` event fires.

Most basic code looks like:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const showSubscription = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", (keyboardEvent) => {
      const screenHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height;
      const keyboardHeight = keyboardEvent.endCoordinates.height;
      setContainerStyle({
        height: screenHeight - keyboardHeight,
      });
    });
    const hideSubscription = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardWillHide", () => {
      setContainerStyle({
        height: "100%",
      });
    });

    return () => {
      showSubscription.remove();
      hideSubscription.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Hopefully that helps